# How to differentiate this exponential process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-differential-equations

I understand how to apply Ito's formula to differentiate the Radon-Nikodym density $Z_t = \exp \bigg(-\int_0^t \theta_sdW_s - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \theta^2_sds \bigg)$ and get the SDE $dZ_t = -\theta_tZ_tdW_t$. However, I don't know how to prove that the derivative of
$$K_t = \exp \bigg(\int_0^t \ln(1+\eta_s) dH_s - \int_0^t \eta_s \zeta_s ds \bigg)$$
is the SDE
$$dK_t = \eta_tK_t (dH_t - \zeta_tdt)$$
where $H_t = I_{\{ \tau \leq t \}}$, $\tau$ is a random time, $\zeta_t$ & $\eta_t$ are a predictable processes and $dH_t-\zeta_tdt$ is a martingale.

Comment: Note that the process $H$ does not have continuous sample paths. Therefore, the usual Ito's lemma needs modification. It is an advanced topic.

Comment: @Danny Pak-Keung Chan Thank you. Do you know of such version of Ito's formula that would help?

Comment: As I said, stochastic processes with jump is an advanced topic.
It cannot be explained in just few lines (or even a paragraph).
 
You may need to consult some advaned textbooks.
For example, 

https://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Integration-Differential-Equations-Hardcover/dp/B010WFL7H2/ref=sr_1_6?dchild=1&keywords=Philip+Protter&qid=1611004952&sr=8-6

Comment: or this one,
https://www.amazon.com/Semimartingale-Theory-Stochastic-Calculus-Sheng-Wu-ebook/dp/B07MF969LG/ref=sr_1_3?crid=2I9WJ8GHYR0KZ&dchild=1&keywords=semimartingale&qid=1611004990&sprefix=Semimartin%2Caps%2C229&sr=8-3

Comment: Thank you @DannyPak-KeungChan